# EE Contact Form With No Redirection

Tags: redirects, css, email-contact-form

I am using EE's built in contact form feature ({exp:email:contact_form}) on my site and it works great.

The issue I have is that the user is shown the following EE page on submit:

[image]

This looks really unprofessional and breaks the experience of the site. Is there a way I can stop this page from being shown? I have tried playing around with the redirect settings but no luck.

Alternatively would there be a way to style the page? For e.g If I was able to add classes to the elements on the page I could hide them in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the parameter [return](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/email/contact_form.html#return) to set the page you want to go to.

The message page can be styled in the control panel. Go to design -> message templates -> user message.

Comment: Perfect! That part about the message page allowed me style that page, solving the problem. Thanks :)